# Store HTML in browserDB using Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, database, electron

I'm trying to store HTML files in the browser for an app built on NW.js or Electron.

Long story short: I want to make something like Sublime Text using a WYSIWYG editor (I don't know exactly how it works, so I will make a guess)

1. Creating a new TAB, all content inside the #editor is store in
   localStorage/IndexedDB/NeDB/PounchDB/LimvoDB/... as the user is
   writing.
2. When the user needs to save the file, it stores the content in the
   browser window, and then it creates the file.
3. If the file already exists, the localStorage content overwrites it.

   **All the magic must happen around the browser DB.**

   You might be wondering why I'm not using files directly, and it's because the first request: We don't know if the user will save the file, but *we don't want to lose all the content if the app is closed*.

   Searching the web, I find that is **bad practice to pass HTML content  through JSON**, but I can't think of any other solution.. I'd have to use encodeURI and decode when retrieve the data to the #editor or the file saved.

I'm using:

- Electron
- Angular
- I don't know yet what DB should I choose

  Digging around, *I also saw the sync function* in PounchDB -> CouchDB and it blew my mind away ─it's a function to synchronize offline and online data using the named DB's.

  Is it possible to store .HTML files in PounchDB and then synchronize it with CouchDB?
  Is all this bad practice?
  How would you do a Notepad - Sublime Text or a «MS Word» editor using PounchDB, or NeDB, or LimvoDB using Electron/NW.js engine?

Comment: what about local storage ? something like this example.. [http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using PouchDB, which also happen to handle very well html-strings.

Comment: I have question o the same, have search online for tutorial but haven't find one. On how to work with CouchBase using PouchDB on angular 2 projects. Do you have a repo I can see how you did it? thanks